# error with bison

Tags: c++, c, bison, yacc

I have a simple rule in my grammar which looks for sequence of whitespaces:

```
    ws: ws|' ';
```

When bison sees this rule, it complains:

warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: ws: ws

Why it is so? Cant I have a simple rule in grammar which looks for a regex?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using left recursion instead?

Comment: I would use the lexer to get all adjacent white space rather than the parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you are declaring is 'ws is ws or ws is a space', not 'ws is one or more spaces'.

If you want the latter, try something like:

```
ws:   ' '
    | ' ' ws;
```

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Recursion

Comment: Note that

       ws: ' ' | ws ' ';

can take significantly less stack space, depending on the length of your runs of whitespace. In general, it's safer to use

       set : element | set element ;

…in Yacc/Bison parsers, since they'll only grow the stack by a maximum of 2 levels, where

       set: element | element set ;

…can grow the stack to its limit (and beyond, crashing the parser) if the input contains arbitrarily-large sets. (Bison defaults to 10,000 stack entries, but it's not impossible to have 10,000 spaces in a file, and it'd be a real pain to debug!)